# How to determine user permissions with Google Directory API

Tags: google-oauth, google-apps, google-apps-marketplace, google-directory-api

Google Apps has several built-in "roles" that have privileges to perform tasks for your domain/organization, for example a Help Desk Admin, Groups Admin or Super User Admin.  [Find them all here](https://support.google.com/a/answer/2405986?hl=en).

We have a console that allows a Google admin to manage which users from that organization/domain should be able to access our App, and we want to limit access to this console only to those admins that have the necessary privileges for the tasks on the console.

However, I simply cannot find a way to determine whether a logged in user has those necessary privileges, short of just trying a couple calls and seeing if they work. Although it's a different Google API, that's exactly [what they tell Google Analytics developers to do here](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/mgmtUserPermissions).

> Retrieving Permissions for the Authorized User
>
> You can retrieve permissions information for the currently authorized
>   user by performing a list or get operation on a Accounts, Web
>   Properties, or Views (Profiles) resource.
>
> To perform these operations the user must authorize either of the
>   following scopes: ....

When you get a list of users from Google Directory API (/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/users), it has only two properties regarding administrator privileges, isAdmin and isDelegatedAdmin.  isAdmin is true for super users and false for everyone else.  isDelegatedAdmin is true for these other types of Admin roles mentioned on the link above.  But there does not seem to be any way to retrieve the more specific admin roles, and even if you could, an organization could create a custom admin role that means you really need to check granular permissions instead of just role.

Has anyone solved this in a more efficient way than trying to call all the necessary APIs to see if the succeed or fail?  I have searched extensively for the better part of a day and cannot find an better solution.

Comment: I should clarify... a representative from Google is the one telling us that we must lock down our admin console to only super users and service level admins, but as described above, we cannot differentiate between service level admins and any other type of delegated admin (helpdesk/group/user), and even if we could, that would still leave the problem of custom admins which may not have all the necessary privileges.  So, Google is requiring us to do this but not giving us a way to do it...

Comment: There is a "Resolved Privileges" screen (from admin.google.com/AdminHome) that displays admin console and admin api privileges for the selected admin user, so I am sure there is an API that does this somewhere?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edited 2018-09-19**

You can retrieve this information using the following endpoints:

- [`Roles`](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/roles) - Returns the roles defined in the organization, including the IDs of the privileges granted to the role.
- [`RoleAssignments`](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/roleAssignments) - Returns the roles that have been assigned to specific users.
- [`Privileges`](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/privileges) - Returns information about the available privileges.

See the [Managing Roles guide](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/manage-roles) for more information.

Comment: Thanks for the response, Eric.  Just to be clear, there really are two issues.  Getting the role seems a lot less important than getting the specific privileges for an admin, especially because there are possible custom admin roles that do not fit neatly into any category and can have any set of privileges so configured.  So, is it safe to assume that there is also not a way to get the specific privileges as well as no way to get the role?

Comment: @EricKoleda still no way to do this?

Comment: Yep, still not possible.

Comment: Is there a way to do this now ??

Comment: It is possible now! Updated with the most recent information.